# overflow: hidden; and z-index aren't able to hide an element beneath it?

Tags: css

So I'm making a menu section on my webpage. I have a dotted line that I want to connect from my menu item to its corresponding price. I'm doing this using the :after pseudo class on each of the menu item's parents. However while everything is aligned, you are able to see the dotted line beneath the menu item and price. I tried using the methods posted in the title but nothing?

```js
const ham = document.querySelector('.nav-box');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuClose = document.querySelector('#menu-close');

ham.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.add('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '50px';
})

menuClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.remove('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '-700px';

})




window.sr = ScrollReveal();

sr.reveal('.info', {
 duration: 2000,
 origin: 'bottom'
})
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
 background: url(img/mex-9.jpg);
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 display: flex;
}

.nav-wrap {
 flex-basis: 40%;
}

.nav-wrap i {
 color: white;
 font-size: 2rem;
 position: absolute;
 right: -33px;
 top: 0px;
 transition: all .1s ease;
}

.nav-wrap i:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 transform: scale(1.15);
}

.nav-box {
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 max-width: 70px;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 10;
}

.b1, .b2, .b3 {
 width: 70px;
 height: 8.5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 transition: all .15s ease;
}

.b1 {
 background-color: #56ff47;
}

.b3 {
 background-color: #ff4c4c;
}

.ham-open .b1 {
 background-color: #56ff47;
 transform: translateY(100px);
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.ham-open .b2 {
 transform: translateY(81.5px);
 width: 110px;
 position: relative;
 left: 60px;
 z-index: 0;
}

.ham-open .b3 {
 background-color: #ff4c4c;
 transform: translateY(63px);
 width: 140px;
 position: relative;
 left: 160px;
 z-index: 2;
}

.menu {
 display: flex;
 border-left: 8px solid #56ff47;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-left: -700px;
 width: 292px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 position: fixed;
 border-radius: 5px;
 top: 225px;
 transition: all .15s;
 z-index: 10;
}

.menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: limegreen;
 font-family: 'Kumar One Outline';
 font-size: 2.3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}

a:hover {
 color: #007001;
}

.info-wrap {
 flex-basis: 60%;
}

.info {
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 4.5rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 60px;
}

.logo-wrap {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.logo-wrap div {
 font-family: 'Staatliches';
 color: white;
 font-size: 13rem;
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
 margin-bottom: -5rem;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;

}



/*------ABOUT------*/



.about-section {
 background-color: #17a832;
 width: 100%;
}

.about-section h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 4.5rem;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 font-weight: bold;
}

.about-wrap {
 display: flex;
 padding-bottom: 150px;
}

.about-info, .image-slider-wrap {
 flex-basis: 50%;
}

.about-info p {
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
}

.image-slider {
 width: 650px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 13px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}

.image-slider i {
 color: white;
 font-size: 5rem;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -40px;
 transition: all .1s ease;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#left {
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 left: -30px;
}

#right {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 right: -30px;
}

#left:hover {
 transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(1.3);
}

#right:hover {
 transform: rotate(90deg) scale(1.3);
}


/*------MENU------*/


.menu-section {
 background-color: #edb12f;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 top: -60px;
 position: relative;
 clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 3%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.menu-section h1 {
 font-size: 9.5rem;
 margin-top: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left: 130px;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 font-weight: bold; 
}

.column-left, .column-right, .column-middle {
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
 margin-top: 230px;
}

.column-left {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}

.column-left .menu-h2:after {
 display: block;
 content: "beans and rice included";
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 margin-top: -25px;
}

.column-middle h2:after, .column-right h2:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-top: -25px;
}

.column-middle {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}

.column-right {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}

.column {
 min-width: 420px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.column h2 {
 display: inline-block;
 align-self: center;
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 color: #17a832;
 font-size: 3rem;
}

.row {
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.row div {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row div:after {
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 33px;
 border-top: 4px dotted black;
}

.price {
 display: inline-block;
 background: #edb12f;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative; 
}

.menu-h2 {
 text-align: center;
}

.design-left, .design-right {
 position: absolute;
}

.design-right {
 right: 0;
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 60px solid green;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}

.arrow-left {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;  
  border-right:60px solid limegreen;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px; 
}

.arrow-top {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent; 
    border-left: 60px solid #20a04b;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  left: 60px;
}

.top-middle {
 position: relative;
 top: -110px;
}

.bottom-middle .arrow-left {
 top: -40px;
}

.bottom-middle .move {
 top: -70px;
}

.bottom {
 position: relative;
 top: -48px;
}

.bottom .arrow-left {
 top: -40px;
}


/*------HOURS------*/

.hours-section {
 background-color: green;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Mexican Restaurant</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive|Josefin+Sans|Kumar+One+Outline|Staatliches" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="header">
   <div class="nav-wrap">
    <div class="nav-box">
     <div class="b1"></div>
     <div class="b2"></div>
     <div class="b3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">About</a>
     <a href="#">Menu</a>
     <a href="#">Hours</a>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
     <a href="#">Location</a>
     <i class="fas fa-times" id="menu-close"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="info-wrap">
    <p class="info">Authentic Mexican Food</p>

    <div class="logo-wrap">
     <div>YOUR</div>
     <div>LOGO</div>
     <div>HERE</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <main>
  <div class="about-section"> 
   <h1 class="about-h1">About Us</h1>

   <div class="about-wrap">
    <div class="about-info">
     <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias voluptas pariatur consequuntur, repellat, laborum, rerum ipsum illo excepturi mollitia reprehenderit saepe nisi praesentium voluptate ab repellendus quos impedit, soluta natus dolore. Praesentium debitis odio cupiditate, reprehenderit alias. Sequi non beatae tempore fugit quia? Ratione aspernatur, quidem voluptates dignissimos Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque quo iure accusantium cupiditate hic, iste ab laborum incidunt neque a nihil, veritatis cumque quaerat, id laboriosam, labore eaque delectus perspiciatis.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="image-slider-wrap"> 
     <div class="image-slider">
      <i class="fas fa-sort-up" id="left"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-sort-up" id="right"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-section">
   <div class="design-left">
    <div class="design-wrap">
     <div class="top">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
      <div class="arrow-top"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="top-middle">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="bottom-middle">
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right move"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="bottom">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-top"></div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="design-wrap">
     <div class="top">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
      <div class="arrow-top"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="top-middle">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="bottom-middle">
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right move"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="bottom">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-top"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="design-right">
    <div class="design-wrap">
     <div class="top">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
      <div class="arrow-top"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="top-middle">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="bottom-middle">
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right move"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="bottom">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-top"></div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="design-wrap">
     <div class="top">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
      <div class="arrow-top"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="top-middle">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="bottom-middle">
      <div class="arrow-right"></div>
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-right move"></div>
     </div>

     <div class="bottom">
      <div class="arrow-left"></div>
      <div class="arrow-top"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>


   <h1>Menu</h1>

   <div class="column-left">
    <div class="column">
     <h2 class="menu-h2" id="combo-platter">Combination Platters</h2>

     <div class="row">
      <div>
       <p>2 Beef Tacos</p>
       <p class="price">$6.99</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>2 Enchiladas</p>
       <p class="price">$6.99</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>Tostada & Enchilada</p>
       <p class="price">$6.99</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>Taco & Enchilada</p>
       <p class="price">$6.99</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>Burrito & Enchilada</p>
       <p class="price">$6.99</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>2 Beef Burritos</p>
       <p class="price">$6.99</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>2 Carne Asada Tacos</p>
       <p class="price">$6.99</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>Carne Asada</p>
       <p class="price">$6.69</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>Chorizo</p>
       <p class="price">$5.99</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>Machaca</p>
       <p class="price">$6.35</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>Carnitas</p>
       <p class="price">$5.89</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>2 Fish Tacos</p>
       <p class="price">$5.99</p>
      </div>
      <div>
       <p>Chiles Rellenos</p>
       <p class="price">$5.95</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="column-middle">
    <div class="column">
     <h2 class="menu-h2">Enchiladas</h2>

     <div class="row">
      <div>
       <p>2 Cheese</p>
       <p class="price">$4.55</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>2 Beef</p>
       <p class="price">$4.65</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>2 Chicken</p>
       <p class="price">$3.55</p>
      </div>
     </div>

     <h2 class="menu-h2">Side Orders</h2>

     <div class="row">
      <div>
       <p>Carne Asada Fries</p>
       <p class="price">$4.55</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>Jalepenos</p>
       <p class="price">$4.65</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>Quesadilla</p>
       <p class="price">$3.55</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>Ham Quesadilla</p>
       <p class="price">$4.55</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>1/2 Pint of beans</p>
       <p class="price">$4.65</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>1/2 Pint of rice</p>
       <p class="price">$4.55</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>Super Nachos</p>
       <p class="price">$4.65</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>1 Tamale</p>
       <p class="price">$4.65</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="column-right">
    <div class="column">
     <h2 class="menu-h2">Enchiladas</h2>

     <div class="row">
      <div>
       <p>2 Cheese</p>
       <p class="price">$4.55</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>2 Beef</p>
       <p class="price">$4.65</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>2 Chicken</p>
       <p class="price">$3.55</p>
      </div>
     </div>

     <h2 class="menu-h2">Side Orders</h2>

     <div class="row">
      <div>
       <p>Carne Asada Fries</p>
       <p class="price">$4.55</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>Jalepenos</p>
       <p class="price">$4.65</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>Quesadilla</p>
       <p class="price">$3.55</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>Ham Quesadilla</p>
       <p class="price">$4.55</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>1/2 Pint of beans</p>
       <p class="price">$4.65</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>1/2 Pint of rice</p>
       <p class="price">$4.55</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>Super Nachos</p>
       <p class="price">$4.65</p>
      </div>

      <div>
       <p>1 Tamale</p>
       <p class="price">$4.65</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hours-section">
   
  </div>
 </main>
 <footer>
  
 </footer>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can use this trick, if you give the price and the item name a gold background and give it a relative positioning so you can take advantage of z-index property it will do the trick for you.

add this code to your css file

```
.menu-section .row p {
    background-color: #edb12f;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Dang I swear I thought I tried that, but it worked.